# DB mysql sql query WHERE EXISTS

Tags: mysql, sql, database, where-clause

i have done a query, in these query i extract a random user and i put a WHERE EXISTS clause, the query work extracting a random user but extract also user without avatar or Skype id, these are the query string :

```
SELECT userid 
   FROM #__session 
     WHERE 
       EXISTS (SELECT 'avatar, cb_skipe' 
                 FROM #__comprofiler 
                   WHERE avatar IS NOT NULL 
                     AND cb_skipe IS NOT NULL) 
     ORDER BY RAND() 
     LIMIT 1;"
```

i need to extract a user randomly with avatar and id Skype

Comment: it doesn't work correctly extract also user without avatar and skype

Comment: Well, you're only selecting `userid` - `SELECT userid `, so of course it's missing the avatar and skype data. If you want that data you'll need to join the `#__comprofiler` table.

Comment: no, i retrieve avatar and Skype id later, for now i need only a user with avatar and id Skype

Comment: I have explained badly

Answer (score 1):

You should link the internal query with the external. Like adding something similar to the internal:

```
AND #__session.user_id = #__comprofiler.user_id
```

Of course I have no idea about your tables/fields, so the field names are guesses only, but somekind of link should exists.